# Subversion - Local Server

Tags: svn, solaris

Looking at installing Subversion to control a large existing project - six developers and currently around 6,000+ source files.

The project exists in a directory tree on the Solaris machine. Developers telnet or ssh to the machine and edit the programs using vi or similar after copying the to their home directories.

Given our current situation, it seems unlikely that we can get a new machine just to act as the svn server so I'm trying to ascertain if we can simply install svnserve locally on the development server and create a folder hidden somehwere in the bowels of the box to house the repository. Given that the `file:/// access` method is supposed to be a little dangerous I presume then that we could still access the respitory by something like `http://hostname/svn/our-project`.

Thoughts? Comments?

Cheers

N/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Large is relative, we (for example) use subversion to manage 80 develoers and about 1.8 million files.

I would gladly recommend you read the [Subversion "red book"](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/).  Fully read at least the first three chapters (and maybe the 4th) then jump straight to the `svnadmin create` command.

After that, you should look into the "svn+ssh" access as a temporary (or even perhaps a permanent) solution until you can evaluate the various pros and cons of the various network transports.

---- Edit after helpful additional commentary ----

If you are currently ssh'ing into a central location, then you can ssh to a subversion server.  So, there's no extra benefit, but then again, there is no extra detriment too.

Setting up a http server actually removes security considering your current setup.  Http traffic is unencrypted, but that might not be such a big concern (depending on whether you care).  What is a bit of a concern is that you will have to manage an Apache Http server, which if you have admins standing by will cause no extra burden.  Otherwise it will.

In addition, managing the http server doesn't get you off the hook managing the subversion repository.  The SVN repository is still there, and still needs to be managed, but you have to manage the http server just to get to the svn repository.  If you start with svn+ssh:// URLs, you can still take that non-http reposistory and put it behind a http server at a later date.

Finally, yes, you can just install the subversion client and admin tools on any existing machine.  I recommend a Linux machine, but that's not the only way to go about it.

As far as "danger" goes, the file:/// access is "dangerous" only if people are in a habit of removing repositories via file erase / rm.  The contents of the repository are equally "exposed" by design in all solutions.  Http wrapped protocols permit per-directory (because it leverages url matching) access controls; but, you probably will never use them (and they impact performance a lot).

In any case, don't bother with a file:/// based anything, the idea is to use network based controls, so svnserve / svnserver+ssh / http / https is what you want.  Then lock down the server to only allow admins file based access to the server repository database.

Then put together a cron + svnadmin dump solution (piped into a compression routine) as a temporary backup script.  Some people even use it to "mirror" closer to remote systems.

Don't forget to routinely test your backups.  Funny how backups seem to work all the time until you need them (then you discover they broke eight months ago, but just looked like they were working).

Good luck

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation.

Comment: Let me try again.
Thank you for the recommendation.
Let me clarify. I have read the first three chapters of the red book repeatedly and the appendices. I have also read through a variety of tutorials and quick-start guides.
I was put off the svn+ssh option as I saw no benefit given the topology in use and after reading the red-book Server Configuration recommendations.
Hence my question.

Comment: @prosmart No protocol is going to change your network topology.  Safety is relative (and not guaranteed).  Avoid file protocol, because you'll then try to do network to file protocol (useless when you have 100% network protocols that really work better).  If you start using a repository under one protocol, you can change protocols later.